# Deleted EC2 (AWS) instance created automatically after 5 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deleted an EC2 (AWS) instance but after 5 minutes it re-created automatically with same name but different ID.

How is possible that?

How can I delete the instance, so will not be created again..

Below is screen short, I delete instance with name pclub, but it has created again..

[image: Instance detail]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This magic must be happening from an [auto-scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html) in your environment. Check whether there is a scaling group and what is the minimum number of instances configured.

Comment: It helped.  I deleted Auto-scaling group, which in reponse removed the new auto-created instance.  I think, problem is solved.. Thanks BTW..